# Mutually disjoint sets

Tags: python

I *thought* I found a solution to the k mutually disjoint sets problem, which is NPC. What is the problem with my solution?

**Edit**

As requested, problem description:

Input: sets A1, ..., An, and a number k.

Question: do there exist k mutually disjoint sets Ai1
, ..., Aik
?

If I am not mistaken, this does not mean that every two groups should be disjoint. right?

Thanks!

```
def Algo(A, k):
    for j in range(len(A)-1):
        final_set=[]
        B= intersect(A[j], A[j+1])
        if len(B)==0:
            final_set.append(A[j])
            final_set.append(A[j+1])
        else:
            continue
        temp= [ v for v in A[j]]
        A[j].extend(A[j+1])
        if j+2<len(A):
            for i in range(j+2, len(A)):
                if len(intersect(A[j], A[i]))==0:
                    final_set.append(A[i])
                    A[j].extend(A[i])
        A[j]= temp
        if len(final_set)>=k:
            return True
    return False
               
def intersect(A, B):
    res= []
    for a in A:
        if a in B:
            res.append(a)
    return res
```

Comment: I guess you are referring to the [Set packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing) problem? Please specify the problem description in your question. Please also fix your code formatting so that it is easier to read. You initialize `final_set` twice, once outside your main loop and once inside your main loop, please remove one of these.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about Set Packing, here is a counter-example on which you algorithm fails: `A = [ [1,2], [2,3] ]` , `k=1`. The answer should be true, because there clearly is a packing `C` of size `1` in `A`, by taking any of the sets in `A`, but your algorithm gives false. This is because your algorithm iterates over the sets in `A`, and checks for each set if the intersection with the previous set is empty. This is not the case for every two pairs in the given ordering of `A`, so your algorithm always goes into the `continue` case.

Comment: The counter-example generalizes for arbitrary `k`. Consider e.g. `A = [ [1,2], [2,3], [3,4] ]` and `k=2`. Again your algorithm gives false, but there is a packing of size `2`, by taking `C = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]`.